# How to make a TextBox with a Button inside in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I'd like to make a `TextBox` with a `Button` inside, something like a `DatePicker`, but not exactly. Or can it be a `ComboBox` inside the `TextBox`, so you can switch the mode of the `TextBox`.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want something like a combobox or a date time picker you should create a new control, inside this new control place a text box and a button side by side inside a frame that looks like the frame of a textbox - then restyle the textbox so it doesn't have a frame.

putting a button inside a rich edit is great if you want to put a button inside a "document" but not a good substitute for a combobox.

See the ComboBox control template [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I actually chose this way in the end. I used Border element to emulate the text box outer border and put the real border-less textbox and a button inside using Grid.

Answer (score 6):

I created a textbox control and added this
It seems to work, but not the ideal situation cos it recreates another textbox.

```
<TextBox.Template>
 <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Grid.Column="1">
            </Button>
        </Grid>         
    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

Comment: I don't think this can work, the text (and other properties) of the outer and inner textbox are not synchronized. You should have used a `PART_ContentHost` named ScrollViewer instead of an inner textbox, like the original template does.

Answer (score 6):

### **Simple solution**

---

You can fake the fact that the button is in the TextBox by putting the Button over the TextBox. Don’t forget to put padding on your TextBox to avoid text going behind the Button.

**Code example with StackPanel :**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Width="200" Padding="0,0,30,0" Height="30" FontSize="16"/>
    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-30,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code example with Grid :**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="200" Padding="0,0,30,0" Height="30" FontSize="16"/>
    <Button Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
</Grid>
```

**Result :**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may find this link helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(VS.85).aspx.

"The ControlTemplate for a TextBox must contain exactly one element that is tagged as the content host element; this element will be used to render the contents of the TextBox. To tag an element as the content host, assign it the special name PART_ContentHost. The content host element must be either a ScrollViewer or an AdornerDecorator. The content host element may not host any child elements."

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichTextBox instead of textbox and it support flowdocument in which you can place the button in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Label and change its template to include a Button in it. To have a good overview of differences between Label and TextBlock see [this post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/).

Answer (score 0):

The correct method of doing this is to use a control template on the textbox. Something like below. I used this inside a class that inherits from textbox and called it ButtonBox. I then inherit others from this such as DateBox, DateTimeBox, SqlServerConnectBox etc.

```
    xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

<TextBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <mwt:ListBoxChrome 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
            RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}"
            RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
            Name="Bd"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

            <DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="myButton" Padding="3,0" Click="myButton_Click">...</Button>
                <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"></ScrollViewer>
            </DockPanel>
        </mwt:ListBoxChrome>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Trigger.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </Trigger.Value>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

Edit: I've change the method I was using so that it inherits from control and not textbox. This works well because the control just consists of a border, a textbox and a button. I was getting focus issues with the above solution. This is new template, I have called my control a ButtonBox

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonBox}">
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE3E9EF" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonBox}">
                <mwt:ListBoxChrome 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}"
                    RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                    Name="Bd"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button
                            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                            Name="PART_Button"
                            Height="0"
                            Style="{x:Null}"
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="3,0"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding local:ButtonBox.ButtonContent}"
                            IsTabStop="False">                                
                        </Button>
                        <TextBox
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Margin="0"
                            Name="PART_ContentHost"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding TextBox.IsReadOnly}"
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Text}">                                
                        </TextBox>
                        <!-- ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="1"></ScrollViewer -->
                    </DockPanel>
                </mwt:ListBoxChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Trigger.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                        </Trigger.Value>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Grid.Column same like below code

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUrl" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="2" PreviewKeyDown="txtUrl_PreviewKeyDown" GotFocus="txtUrl_GotFocus" PreviewMouseDown="txtUrl_PreviewMouseDown"> 

</TextBox>
<eo:BareButton x:Name="btnAddFavorite" Grid.Column=" 1"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle }" Margin="2" >
    <eo:BareButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type eo:BareButton}">
            <Border x:Name="PART_Border" Width="22" Height="22" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" CornerRadius="2">
                <Path 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Fill="Yellow" 

            Data="M 2,9 L 8,8 10,2 13,8 19,9 15,13 16,19 10,15 5,19 6,13 2,9"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type eo:BareButton}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
            StrokeThickness="1" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#666"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </eo:BareButton.Template>

</eo:BareButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use a grid to accomplish this task. The following is how I created a button which appears at the right bottom of a TextBox:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" />

        <Button Content="Copy" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" />

</Grid>
```