# Can I place controls inside Textbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox

For example Button, Link, Image ,...
This code does not work:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="180" 
        Margin="38,35,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="TextBox" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="442"
        >
        <Button 
            Content="Button" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="149,105,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="-2.78,1.376"
            />
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: hint: make use of control templates.

Comment: You can't do that. You can superimpose it on top of the TextBox, but you'll have to get creative to make the scrolling work as you want. What is your actual goal here? There's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not without writing your own custom control. That is the proper solution.

Here is a good example of a custom control for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419556/1624581

Alternatively, **as a hacky and quick solution** you could put the button and the textbox in a container (e.g. stackpanel or grid) and then use a negative margin on the button so that it appears within the textbox. You can then apply a padding on the right of the textbox so that the input text doesn't overlap with the button. With that said, **I'd strongly recommend writing a custom control** as negative margins can cause maintenance headaches in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to put controls programmatically. I mean there is a button outside of the Textbox that will add an Image inside the Textbox! Furthermore, I'd like the control go up and down as I scroll the Textbox.